# Como fazer para os post do blog aparecerem na pagina quando clicar no menu?

Tags: html, blogger

Tenho um blogger, já criei postagens, quero fazer o seguinte:
Quero relacionar o menu as postagens: quando eu clicar no menu aparecerá todos os post relativos.

Comment: Você poderia explicar mais detalhadamente o que exatamente você está tentando fazer? Já tentou algum código? Pode compartilhá-lo junto da sua pergunta?

Comment: @kazzkiq quando eu clico em um menu abre uma página especifica dentro desta página tem as publicações(post) quero fazer isso no meu blog.

Comment: @MarianaGomes, este é um site voltado para programação. Se até onde sei o blogger limita muito o quanto pode alterar. Mas, não é o objetivo deste site te dar um código pronto. Tente fazer e poste suas **dúvidas.**

Comment: Mariana, precisaria saber como é a estrutura do seu menu de postagens e em qual `<div>` (ou outro elemento) você quer que o conteúdo seja carregado. Poderia editar sua pergunta adicionando esses trechos de código?

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi bem, o que você quer fazer é filtrar posts por tag. No menu os links deverão apontar para a tag relacionada a publicação.

**Exemplo:** 
http://seusite.blogspot.com.br/search/label/Noticias

Nesse caso filtraria publicações que tem a tag *Noticias*